# How to set an EditText?

Tags: android

How to set Edit Text in Android Studio to be able enter 1-22 on Mobile?
**android:inputType="numberSigned"** does not work.

In this case I can write **-122** but not **1-22**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With type :

> android:inputType="phone"

you can write 1-22